# Is there an overfitting in the data?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, error, overfitting

In my training set, I have 4026 instances, two classes and 104 attributes.

The training error (error on the entire training set) is about 14% and 10 fold CV error on the training set is about 27%.

Does this mean that my model is overfitting the training data?

**EDIT (More Results):**

- Total Instance 4026 (+: 951, -:3075)
- Model Random forest (default settings in Weka)
- Training Error:14%, 10 Fold CV Error: 27%, Training F-score (+):67%, Training F-score (-): 91%, 10 Fold CV F-score (+): 31%, 10 Fold CV F-score (-): 83%
- After Random Undersampling, Total Instance 1902 (+ and -:951 each)
- After Random Undersampling, Training Error:16%, 10 Fold CV Error: 36%, Training F-score (+):85%, Training F-score (-): 84%, 10 Fold CV F-score (+): 65%, 10 Fold CV F-score (-): 63%

Comment: Are your classes well balanced? I.e. the number of instances belonging to class 1 is almost similar to the number of instances of class 2. The reason I'm asking is that If you have a very unbalanced data set and your classifier classifies all (or most) instances as majority class you will still get good results which might or might not indicate overfitting, even with CV in case stratified sampling was used.

Comment: My classes are not balanced. The ration of positive:negative is 1:3. I have taken a look at the precision, recall and F-score for the positive and negative classes. The f-score of positive class is about 67% and negative class is 91% on training set. When I am doing a 10 fold CV on the training set, I get F-score of positive class about 31% and negative class about 83%.

Comment: If I do a random undersampling to make the data 50-50 (equally distributed to each class), then: Training error 16%. Training F-score (+) 85%, Training F-score (-) 84%, 10 fold CV error 36%, 10 fold CV F-score (+) 65%, 10 fold CV F-score (-) 63%. I am using Random Forest implementation in Weka.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily. It is normal for the training error to be lower than the generalization error. Cross-validation is one way to estimate the generalization error. Lower generalization performance does not necessarily indicate an overfit.

The reason for this is simple: **your model is constructed to optimally fit the training data** with some additional criteria to limit its complexity (such as regularization). In other words, it is normal that the model predicts training data at least as well as unseen data.

An overfit happens when your model *only* fits the training set well and completely breaks down on unseen data. Because the difference you are seeing is fairly large an overfit is possible here. As a next step you can try to make a new model with lower complexity and see if the difference between training set accuracy and CV accuracy diminishes. If it does, your original model was an overfit.

You may also want to check out this: [How to assess overfitting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/how-to-assess-overfitting)

Comment: So, the 10 fold CV error is kind of saying that if I apply the model on unseen data, the error will be around 27%?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that the unseen data is distributed like the training data (which is a fair assumption but not always true in practice).

Comment: "Because the difference you are seeing is fairly large an overfit is possible here"- is there any "standard difference" by which you can say that the possibility of overfitting is there?

Comment: @RushdiShams this answer may be useful to answer that question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/5099/25433

Answer (score 4):

We tend to say that a model is over-fit if it performs very well on the training set, but does abysmally on some held-out data.

Models are typically trained by adjusting their parameters to maximize the training set performance[*], so you should expect test-set performance to be slightly worse. A model that goes from 100% accuracy on the training data to 50% accuracy on held-out data is clearly over-fit and one that only drops a few points probably isn't, but there is no bright line between the two categories.  Your results aren't setting off any alarm bells, but it might be worth considering whether you can get more data or adjust some regularization parameters.

Keep in mind that training performance is just a useful diagnostic. High training error can indicate that something is wrong: perhaps the algorithm cannot represent the underlying concept, something is pathological about your choice of hyperparameters, or the training data is very noisy. On the other hand, low training error is a terrible predictor of future performance: it can indicate successful training OR over-fitting. As such, people rarely report it since we mostly care about how the algorithm will perform on new data.

Comment: thanks. So, besides the problem, is it always a good idea to mention the training error (error on training set) besides fantastic 10 fold CV error in published work? For instance, a 10 fold CV error can be 10% while a training error can be 0%. I have seen that in my area people who do 10 fold CV, do not report training error.

Comment: There's nothing *stopping* you from reporting the training error, but it's not terribly useful by itself. Test error, since it predicts future results, is the more interesting quantity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to slightly disagree with some of the answers up here. In my opinion, overfitting does not necessarily mean "abysmally" poor performance on the test set. You can be in an overfitting situation and yet achieve apparently good test error. Yet decreasing the model complexity may decrease generalisation error - which means the model has indeed overfit, although it may not be obvious from test error.

Either way we can't really answer your answer as is; first, overfitting is usually understood as related to model complexity, and we don't know what your model is. You might want to try and train your model using various levels of complexity (for instance, if it's gradient boosting, vary the number of trees or shrinkage, if it's a GLM, add a regularization term, etc.). Then it will become obvious when your model has begun to overfit.

Otherwise we can't tell from a single observation if the model is grossly overfitting the training data (unless, obviously, the test error is through the roof).

Comment: So, even if someone's test error is good (so is the training error), s/he needs to examine whether the model did overfit or not?

Comment: Of course, unless s/he considers 27% test error is tolerable for his purposes. Otherwise there is absolutely no reason not to try and tune parameters to lower validation error and hence achieve lower test error. Also, training error really has no value unless you're using very low complexity models such as very low-dimensional parametric models.

Comment: @Youloush: ... given that there is other, still independent, test data to validate the the final tuned model as the former test data is now used for the tuning and thus not independent any more.

Comment: We don't even know what the model is, but validation can in many cases be achieved through cross-validation, which doesn't require a validation set (and usually works even better, provided computation time isn't a problem).